# What API methods are there to determine a company's market cap?

Tags: programming, yahoo

I'm wondering what API methods there are to determine a company's market cap, i.e. (number of shares issued) * (price per share).

I know IQfeed and perhaps Yahoo will do this - does anyone know of any other API's that will do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Yahoo Query Language (YQL) blog: [Getting stock information with YQL and open data tables](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2009/06/02/getting-stock-information-with-yql-and-open-data-tables/).

Go to the [YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/DEiCg2SN), and use the following query:

```
select MarketCapitalization from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL")
```

Here is key part of the result:

```
<results>
    <quote>
        <MarketCapitalization>20.508B</MarketCapitalization>
    </quote>
    <quote>
        <MarketCapitalization>317.5B</MarketCapitalization>
    </quote>
</results>
```

Once you have the result in .xml, its easy to query it using LINQ in C#.

Answer (score 8):

I know you mentioned that you already know about Yahoo's ability to do this. However, I thought I'd add the following snippet on how to do this with Yahoo. It's a trivial HTTP Get, and is likely the quickest and easiest way to get the information you're after:

```
> curl "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CSCO&f=j1"
86.991B
```

That will return a single result with one entry, which is the market cap of the stock you supplied. You can also supply more than one stock:

```
> curl "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CSCO,AAPL&f=j1"
86.991B
355.9B
```

Comment: Sadly, this service was discontinued by Yahoo:

    curl "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=CSCO&f=j1"
    
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: download.finance.yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

The Zacks API should have this data, see http://www.zacksdata.com/zacks-data-api

*(Disclosure: The API is managed by my company)*