# Is there an API that can return the current market cap of a publicly-traded company?

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, visualization, market-capitalization

I am trying to find an API which will return the current market cap of US stocks for a financial data visualization project, and I haven't had much luck finding anything. Preferably, I'd like to have market cap data for all S&P 500 stocks, though I realize that something like this might not be available and that I may just need to create that list myself with other data.

Has anyone had luck getting market cap data from an API, or is there a relatively simple way that I could calculate the market caps?

I've checked out [this old post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/what-api-methods-are-there-to-determine-a-companys-market-cap) where someone suggested Yahoo finance and YQL, but the links are unfortunately dead and it appears as though this service is no longer offered.

Thanks for any insight/advice!

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick and easy solution, I have found a combination of Google Sheets + Yahoo Finance URLs to be relatively easy to implement.

Here's an example you could try yourself. Let's say you have a stock ticker, "AAPL" in cell A1.

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML( CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/", A2,"?p=",A2,"&.tsrc=fin-srch")  ,"table",2),1,2)
```

Basically, the importhtml function I've specified above will go to Yahoo Finance, then look for this table, splitting it out into 2 columns illustrated in yellow and only pull in the observation found in the first row, second column (hence the 1, 2 in the function parameters):

[image]

This approach could effortlessly be extended for all S&P500 companies - you would just put their corresponding ticker in cell A3 onward.

In order to pull in a list of all S&P500 constituents, you could go to [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) to get a list using a similar formula. Be warned that if you intend to do any historical analysis, companies get listed/delisted all the time and your analysis could reflect [suvivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias).